# Finding unique solutions to $w+x + y + z + w = 0$, faster

Tags: equation-solving

Using `Solve`, I can find the solutions to $$ w + x + y + z = 0. $$ where $(w,x,y,z)$ are all integers between $-n$ and $n$.

This gives me all solutions, including ones which are identical up to permutation, *i.e.* $(1,0,1,-2)$ and $(0,1,-2,1)$. But I would like to consider these both to be the same solution.

Using `DeleteDuplicates` it's easy enough to get the unique solutions (up to permutations), but both of these steps use up much more time than just generating non-duplicate solutions in the first place.

My questions is: is there a way to generate non-duplicate solutions, and efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much faster approach using [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html)

```
fs[n_]:=IntegerPartitions[0, {4}, Range[-n, n]];
```

For `n=3`

> {{3, 3, -3, -3}, {3, 2, -2, -3}, {3, 1, -1, -3}, {3, 1, -2, -2}, {3, 
>     0, 0, -3}, {3, 0, -1, -2}, {3, -1, -1, -1}, {2, 2, -1, -3}, {2, 
>     2, -2, -2}, {2, 1, 0, -3}, {2, 1, -1, -2}, {2, 0, 0, -2}, {2, 
>     0, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, -3}, {1, 1, 0, -2}, {1, 1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, 
>     0, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}

**Timing comparison:**

```
fa[n_] := {w, x, y, z} /. 
  Solve[w + x + y + z == 0 && LessEqual @@ {-n, w, x, y, z, n}, {w, x,
     y, z}, Integers] (*Bob's solution *)

fa[40];// AbsoluteTiming
fs[40];// AbsoluteTiming
Sort[(Sort /@ fa[40])] == Sort[(Sort /@ fs[40])]
```

> {0.234222, Null}
>
> {0.00182044, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Beat me to it. This is the way to do it +1

Answer (score 4):

To avoid duplicates order the variables, i.e., `w <= x <= y <= z`

```
With[{n = 3},
 {w, x, y, z} /. 
  Solve[w + x + y + z == 0 &&
    And @@ Thread[-n <= {w, x, y, z} <= n] &&
      w <= x <= y <= z, {w, x, y, z}, Integers]]

(*  {{-3, -3, 3, 3}, {-3, -2, 2, 3}, {-3, -1, 1, 3}, {-3, -1, 2, 2}, {-3, 0, 0, 
  3}, {-3, 0, 1, 2}, {-3, 1, 1, 1}, {-2, -2, 1, 3}, {-2, -2, 2, 2}, {-2, -1, 
  0, 3}, {-2, -1, 1, 2}, {-2, 0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1, 
  3}, {-1, -1, 0, 2}, {-1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}  *)
```

**EDIT:**  As suggested by [`jiaoeyushushu`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/35486/jiaoeyushushu) this can be written more succinctly as

```
With[{n = 3}, {w, x, y, z} /. 
  Solve[w + x + y + z == 0 && LessEqual @@ {-n, w, x, y, z, n}, {w, x, y, z}, 
   Integers]]
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: And @@ Thread[-n <= {w, x, y, z} <= n] && w <= x <= y <= z   ->   -n <= w <= x <= y <= z <= n

Comment: @jiaoeyushushu - Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
  falucard[n_] := Reduce[ w + x + y + z == 0   && LessEqual @@ {-n, w, x, y, z, n} , {w, x, y, z}, Integers];
galucard[n_] :=  Apply[List, falucard[n][[All, All, 2]], {0, 1}] 


     fs[28]; // AbsoluteTiming          
fbob[28]; // AbsoluteTiming
galucard[28]; // AbsoluteTiming

galucard[3]*(-1) == fs[3] == fbob[3]*(-1)
```

> {0.000673695,Null}
>
> {0.110799,Null}
>
> {0.0617464,Null}
>
> True